# Проблема при установке шаблона Wordpress BierBaum

Tags: php, wordpress

Устанавливаю шаблон на зарубежный шаблон на php 5.2.17-2+mh1

```
  uasort($BIERBAUM_GLOBALS['shortcodes'], function($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
        }
```

При установке на php 5.5.36 тема прекрано работает. В чем состоит ошибка для данной версии?

Comment: Анонимные функции введены в php начиная с версии 5.3.

Comment: Спасибо, можете отправить в ответ?

Comment: У меня заработало только при установке php 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению на хостинге стояла устаревшая версия PHP 5.2, с которой не мог работать Wordpress 4.0 согласно спецификации.
https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_WordPress